# Proving that three lines within a triangle are concurrent

Tags: geometry

`If D, E, and F are the midpoints of the sides BC, CA, and AB of triangle ABC, and AP, BP, CP meet the opposite sides in L, M, and N, P being any point in the plane, prove that the joins of D, E, and F to the midpoints of AL, BM, and CN are concurrent.`

[image: Diagram]

Because P is barycentric and contained on several lines, I know that:

$P = k_1A+k_2B+k_3C$

$P = rA+(1-r)L = sB+(1-s)M = tC+(1-t)N$

but I am not sure whether this really does much good, as $L$,$M$, and $N$ are of the form $kP_1+(1-k)P_2$ as well.
I tried to directly compute the lines from $D$,$E$, and $F$ through the midpoints of the respective segments, but I'm not sure what to do afterward, because nothing in the system becomes easier to manipulate:

$D-\frac{1}{2}AL = \frac{1}{2}B+C-\frac{1}{2}A-\frac{1}{2}L$

$E-\frac{1}{2}BM = \frac{1}{2}A+\frac{1}{2}C-\frac{1}{2}B-\frac{1}{2}M$

$F-\frac{1}{2}CN = \frac{1}{2}A+\frac{1}{2}B-\frac{1}{2}C-\frac{1}{2}N$

I've probably done this completely wrong, so I would appreciate any tips or pointers on how to proceed or approach the problem. It just seems like there's so many ways to approach the problem that I don't know where to begin.

Answer (score 1):

Why not try a geometric solution. The key is Ceva's Theorem. It given points L,M,N on BC,CA,AB the lines AL,BM,CN are concurrent iff a particular product of three ratios is 1. Then you use the triangle DEF. The three midpoints lie on the sides of that triangle hand have the same value.